# How can i get the version info of flume in use of my cluster(cloudera CDH5.5.1)?

Tags: version, cloudera, flume, flume-ng

I am using Cloudera CDH5.5.1, how can i find the version of flume I am using?

Is there any commands I can get this information, like some 'hadoop version'?

thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can issue the command `flume-ng version` on the/any host to get the version.

Comment: @Colin.Fu : Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**From Cloudera Manager**

Login to the Cloudera Manager and goto Hosts page then run `inspect hosts` in cluster

**Over CLI**

`flume-ng version`